# HAML in Rails 3 produces only doctype html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xhtml, haml

I am running into a problem:

If use something like this:

```
!!! XML
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Myspace
  %body
    %h1 I am the international space station
    %p Sign my guestbook
```

I get only this as source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Myspace</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>I am the international space station</h1>
    <p>Sign my guestbook</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the [HAML documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#doctype_), XHTML is the default DOCTYPE apart from for Rails 3 which uses HTML5. You can set the `:format` option to override.

In `config/environment.rb`:

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :xhtml
```

Answer (score 6):

For me it doesn't work to put it in `environment.rb`.

I set up an initializer in `config/initializers/haml.rb` and put in it...

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :xhtml
```

Be sure to restart the server after adding that.

Then in my pages...

```
!!! XML
!!!
```

This produces...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```